# Reinstall ubuntu 18.04 (Grayed color )

Tags: reinstall

I was trying to reinstall Ubuntu without losing my files, but at the "Installation type" screen the "Reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" option is greyed out so I can't select it. Please help me out how to fix it?